# PHP link list, outputing first and last

Tags: php, algorithm, logic

I'm trying to build a linkList. Everything is working fine, except  my function `createLinkList`. There is an if condition to specify if its the first entry. I think the issue is with my logic in the `else`. Can anyone stop whats going on?

I would expect an output from my example to be something like

```
object(createLinkList)#1 (1) {
  ["head"]=>
  object(node)#2 (2) {
    ["data":"node":private]=>
    string(4) "adam"
    ["link":"node":private]=>
    object(node)#3 (2) {
      ["data":"node":private]=>
      string(4) "andy"
      ["link":"node":private]=>
      object(node)#4 (2) {
          ["data":"node":private]=>
          string(4) "ben"
          ["link":"node":private]=>
      }
          //and so on...
    }
  }
}
```

instead I'm getting;

```
object(createLinkList)#1 (1) {
  ["head"]=>
  object(node)#2 (2) {
    ["data":"node":private]=>
    string(4) "adam"
    ["link":"node":private]=>
    object(node)#3 (2) {
      ["data":"node":private]=>
      string(4) "eric"
      ["link":"node":private]=>
      *RECURSION*
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code, it should run fine. Would really appreciate someone explaining what im doing wrong. Thanks

```
$oLinkList = new createLinkList;
$oLinkList->createLinkList($aList);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($oLinkList);


class createLinkList{

    // // link to the first node
    public $head;
    // link to the last node
    // public $tail;
    // public $next;


    //mutator method
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }

    //accessor method
    public function __get($property) {

        if (isset($this->$property)) {

            return $this->$property;

        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }


    // init the properties
    function __construct() {
        $this->head = null;
        // $this->tail = null;
      // $this->previous = null;

    }


    function createLinkList($aList){

        if($aList == null || empty($aList)){        
            //$this = null;
            return null;
        }

        $oPrevious;

        foreach ($aList as $data) {

            // create node/object 
            $link = new Node($data);


            // first entry, have already created the node, so save a reference to in in the head var
            if($this->head == null){

                $this->head = $link;
                $oPrevious = &$this->head;

            }else{ // update the previous nodes link with a pointer to the node createds

                $oPrevious->link = $link;
                // $this->previous= $link;
                $link->link = $this->head;

               //$this->head = $link;
            }
        }
    }

}// end class



class node{

    private $data = null;
    private $link;


    //mutator method
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }

    //accessor method
    public function __get($property) {

        if (isset($this->$property)) {

            return $this->$property;

        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }



    /* Node constructor */
    function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->link = null;
    }


}
```

Comment: thanks whoever it was for downvoting and not bothering to tell me why. Isnt this a Q+A site?

Comment: What are you intending to achieve with the line `$oPrevious;` actually?

Comment: I'm not sure, probably was thinking i needed to declare it before use. I will remove it, thanks

Comment: @Victor have you got any idea what im doing wrong? it feels like I'm not too far off. Thanks

Comment: A lot.
You actually only update `head` when it is already null, but you only set it to null.
You also do nothing with `oPrevious`.

Comment: thanks Victor, makes sense will have a look

Answer (score 1):

You should never update the previous element unless you delete one.

You should always store the first element only, and set its next to a new node when needed.

This should be handled by a method and not foreach though.

Comment: thanks really apprecaite this! Will have a look and post an update of code when its done. Thank you!